# Array is filled with promises... that should be fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise

I thought that after Promise.all and then() - all promises should be fulfilled (resolved), and when I console.log the results array it seems the are (testArr2) BUT when I try to copy the values from this array - it seems that Promises are on the run (testArr3)...

```js
var dataArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
var testArr1 = [];
var testArr2 = [];
var testArr3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
  testArr1.push(f1(dataArr[i]));
}

function f1(one) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      testArr2.push(f2(one));
      resolve(one + 'aaaaaaaaaaa');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function f2(one) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(one + 'bbbbbbbbbb');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

Promise.all(testArr1).then(function(testArr1) {
  console.log(testArr1);
}).then(function() {
  console.log('==========================');
  console.log('==========================');
  console.log('==========================');
}).then(function() {
  return Promise.all(testArr2).then(function(testArr2) {
    console.log(testArr2); // fulfilled...
  });
}).then(function() {
  testArr2.map(function(item) {
    testArr3.push(item);
  });
  console.log(testArr3); // promises inside...
});
```

Any idea why promises are pending?

Comment: Why aren't you using the argument inside the `then` chain function callbacks?

Comment: global `testArr2` is an array of Promises - and you never change that ... then second `testArr2` in `Promise.all(testArr2).then(function(testArr2)` is not the same as the global `testArr2` that you use `.map` on - the problem is your understanding of a variables scope rather than anything to do with Promises

Comment: @Bravo could you elaborate? Cause "return Promise.all(testArr2).then(function(testArr2)" seems to resolve all promises, otherwise I could not work on the array, right? EDIT - you did EDIT the comment, now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: `return Promise.all(testArr2).then(function(testArr2)` does not resolve anything - the promises resolve when they resolve - the callback is called once all the promises resolve - but the global `testArr2` is still an array of Promises forever

Comment: @Proo1931 The global `testArr2` variable and the `testArr2` parameter of your callback function are two different arrays. Name them differently to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Bergi yea that is what confused me and Bravo pointed that out. But another question come to my mind - if I call Promise.all for testArr2 (the array that got all the Promises object) AGAIN - it will run immediately (and give me resolved array), right? Cause it already has all those promises inside it RESOLVED ? - it do not need to wait for any asynchronous task I put there, it just give me results, right ?

Comment: @Proo1931 `Promise.all` always gives you a promise. Yes, that promise will be immediately fulfilled if all the promises in the array are already fulfilled. The `then` callback you might install on that promise will always run asynchronously, but it is schedule immediately since the promise is already fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that out for me. Any idea why mapping an array of Promises object and resolving the item with Promise.resolve do not work? testArr2.map(function(item){Promise.resolve(item); newArray.push(item); // still a Promise object});